# Process TCP/IP data from buffer in Python

Tags: python, sockets, numpy, stream, tcp

I am building a Python class with connects to OpenVibe software via TCP/IP and will read EEG data which this software streams.

OpenVibe is open-source software which records EEG and it is able to send data over TCP/IP to another computer for processing. I want to process it at the same computer at localhost and then control some Arduino stuff. But I stucked at recieving the stream.

There is documentation at OpenVibe website which is not so clear to me:
http://openvibe.inria.fr/documentation/1.2.0/Doc_BoxAlgorithm_TCPWriter.html

So far I understand I need to read data by bytes from buffer and take care of channels and samples which varies every packet, which is described in docuemntation 2b table.

As I use code I do:

1. connect to server
2. read every 32 bytes in while loop

I need to somehow process data from buffer, but don't know how.

There is my whole Python 3 class using macOS 10.12.4:
https://gist.github.com/neuropacabra/3dbeed04fd0d6a257476af1e0ff36567

I guess main problem is in function `readstream()` when calling `while strreaming` loop.

```
def readstream(self, info = True):
    try:
        import numpy
    except:
        print("Cannot import numpy module")

    if self.header_readed:
        print("Reading the TCPWritter stream...")
        stream = []
        eeg_data = []
        is_streaming = True

        while is_streaming:
            try:
                stream = numpy.frombuffer(self.sock.recv
                                          (self.samples_per_chunk), 
                                          dtype = numpy.float32, 
                                          count = -1)
            except:
                print("Cannot read datastream")
            if numpy.size(stream) != 0:
                eeg_data.append(stream)
                if info:
                    print(stream)
                return stream                    
            else:
                is_streaming = False
                self.disconnect()
                print("No data in buffer, socket is closed.")
    else:
        print("No header was read. Cannot recieve datastream.")
```

I need to able to process data from buffer in manner as OpenVibe documentation says which is:

```
| Name                  | Type          | Bytes from start   |
| --------------------  | ------------- | ------------------ |
| Channel 1, sample 1   | float64       | 32 + (k*0+0)*8     |
| Channel 1, sample 2   | float64       | 32 + (k*0+1)*8     |
| ...                   | ...           | ...                |
| Channel 1, sample k   | float64       | 32 + (k*0+(k-1))*8 | 
| Channel 2, sample 1   | float64       | 32 + (k*1+0)*8     |
| Channel 2, sample 2   | float64       | 32 + (k*1+1)*8     |
| ...                   | ...           | ...                |
| Channel 1, sample k+1 | float64       | 32 + (k*n+0)*8     |
| ...                   | ...           | ....               |
```

Lets say I would use 4 channels to stream. I will OpenVibe to send data over TCP/IP as table suggests but I am not able to read it correctly. Now I get some random values because I don't parse buffer data so I basically read all the data.

How do I should code to read all samples in time for channel 1, channel 2, channel 3 and channel 4?

Thank you in advice!

Michael

Comment: What happens when you run the code, error messages, etc.?

Comment: @postoronnim - I don't get any error I simply read all sent values and it seems like random when I compare original signals and my recieved signal in line plots.